# arc.js installation in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I have project developed in Angular 5 with Node.js . Now in my project I want to have flight animation connections and used the example of OpenLayers called 'Flight Animation'. The problem is that there is a library called 'arc.js' used in example which I could not import it. I installed the library using 'npm install --save arc' but still 'arc' is not recognized. My code is :

```js
import { ElementRef, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

    import Map from 'ol/map';
    import View from 'ol/view';
    import Proj from 'ol/proj';

//Layers
    import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
    import LayerVector from 'ol/layer/vector';
    import SourceVector from 'ol/source/vector';
    import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
    import Feature from 'ol/feature';

//Image WMS
    import Image from 'ol/layer/Image';
    import ImageWMS from 'ol/source/ImageWMS';
    import WMSGetFeatureInfo from 'ol/format/WMSGetFeatureInfo';
    import TileImage from 'ol/source/tileimage';

//Popup
    import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay';
    import arc from 'arc/arc.js';
//OpenLayers Styles
    import Style from 'ol/style/style';
    import Stroke from 'ol/style/stroke';
    import Fill from 'ol/style/fill';
    import Text from 'ol/style/text';
    import Circle from 'ol/style/circle';
    import Icon from 'ol/style/icon';

//Graphic Types
    import Geometry from 'ol/geom/geometry';
    import Point from 'ol/geom/point';
    import MultiPoint from 'ol/geom/multipoint';
    import MultiPolygon from 'ol/geom/multipolygon';
    import Extent from 'ol/extent';


//Cluster
    import Cluster from 'ol/source/cluster';

//HeatMap
    import Heatmap from 'ol/layer/Heatmap';
    import KML from 'ol/format/kml';

//BaseMaps
    import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
    import BingMaps from 'ol/source/BingMaps';

//OpenLayers Interaction
    import olInteraction from 'ol/interaction';
    import InteractionMouseWheelZoom from 'ol/interaction/mousewheelzoom';

//WKT
import Wkt from 'ol/format/wkt';

//Loading Strategy
    import loadingstrategy from 'ol/loadingstrategy';

//Animation
    import Easing from 'ol/easing';

    import LineString from 'ol/geom/linestring';

    import Stamen from 'ol/source/stamen';

//Control ?
    import Control from 'ol/control';
    import { LayersService } from '../layer-service/layers.service';
    import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
    import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import { headersToString } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
    import { NavbarService } from '../navbar-service/navbar.service';
    import { LayerType } from '../enums/layer-type.enum';
    import { UtilService } from '../util-service/util.service';
    import { RequestService } from '../request-service/request.service';
    import { OverlayComponent } from '../overlay/overlay.component';
    lineAnimation(){

           var style = new Style({
             stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#EAE911',
        width: 2
      })
    });

    var flightsSource;
    var addLater = function (feature, timeout) {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        feature.set('start', new Date().getTime());
        flightsSource.addFeature(feature);
      }, timeout);
    };
    var pointsPerMs = 0.1;
    var animateFlights = function (event) {
      var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
      var frameState = event.frameState;
      vectorContext.setStyle(style);
      var features = flightsSource.getFeatures();
      for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        var feature = features[i];
        if (!feature.get('finished')) {
          // only draw the lines for which the animation has not finished yet
          var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
          var elapsedTime = frameState.time - feature.get('start');
          var elapsedPoints = elapsedTime * pointsPerMs;

          if (elapsedPoints >= coords.length) {
            feature.set('finished', true);
          }
          var maxIndex = Math.min(elapsedPoints, coords.length);
          var currentLine = new LineString(coords.slice(0, maxIndex));

          // directly draw the line with the vector context
          vectorContext.drawGeometry(currentLine);
        }
      }
      // tell OpenLayers to continue the animation
      this.Map.render();
    };
    flightsSource = new SourceVector({
      wrapX: false,
      attributions: 'Flight data by ' +
        '<a href="http://openflights.org/data.html">OpenFlights</a>,',
      loader: function () {
        var url = 
    'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/openflights/flights.json';
        fetch(url).then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function (json) {
          var flightsData = json.flights;
          for (var i = 0; i < flightsData.length; i++) {
            var flight = flightsData[i];
            var from = flight[0];
            var to = flight[1];
            // create an arc circle between the two locations
            var arcGenerator = new arc.GreatCircle(
              { x: from[1], y: from[0] },
              { x: to[1], y: to[0] });

            var arcLine = arcGenerator.Arc(100, { offset: 10 });
            if (arcLine.geometries.length === 1) {
              var line = new LineString(arcLine.geometries[0].coords);
              line.transform(Proj.get('EPSG:4326'), Proj.get('EPSG:3857'));

              var feature = new Feature({
                geometry: line,
                finished: false
              });
              // add the feature with a delay so that the animation
              // for all features does not start at the same time
              addLater(feature, i * 50);
            }
          }
          this.Map.on('postcompose', animateFlights);
        });
      }
    });
    var flightsLayer = new LayerVector({
      source: flightsSource,
      style: function (feature) {
        // if the animation is still active for a feature, do not
        // render the feature with the layer style
        if (feature.get('finished')) {
          return style;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    });
    this.map.addLayer(flightsLayer);
    }
```

I get the error in 'var arcGenerator = new arc.GreatCircle('

Answer (score 1):

You may want to "browserified" the bundle is was developped for Node.js and Browser support but not for import syntax.

```
git clone https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js.git
cd arc.js
npm install
npm install browserify
./node_modules/.bin/browserify arc.js --standalone arc > arc-browserified.js
```

You can also use one of Turf packages e.g [line-arc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/line-arc) that does the same as "arc.js" and it works well with Webpack/import